# How to find $a$ and $b$

Tags: matrices

I require to find $a$ and $b$ in the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\-40\\25\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1\\-4\\3\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I moved the $b[\ ]$ group to the other side and now here I am guessing but I would require to find the a matrix inverse so I can isolate a but I seem to be missing something or I do not fully understand it. Can someone help me with what steps is needed to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just a matter of solving this system:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&a+b=0\\
&-4a+4b=-40\\
&3a-2b=25
\end{align*}\right.$$

Of course it could turn out to be inconsistent, though in this case it doesn’t.

You **can** set it up as a matrix problem, but that strikes me as a bit of overkill. The system above can be written

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-4&4\\3&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-40\\25\end{bmatrix}$$

and solved in any of the usual ways.

Comment: Aww cool, I was looking at as a matrix and not a system, Thanks.

Comment: @Reza: You’re welcome. (I’m lazy: I almost always look for the easiest way!)

Answer (score 1):

You have the equations 
\begin{align*}
0 &= a+b\\
-40 &= -4a +4b\\
25 &= 3a-2b\\
\end{align*}
Solve it :)